# Calculating total price

Tags: java

I have an abstract class `Transaction`, where I would like to calculate total price of each `Transaction`. The total price is calculated by getting the price of each `Product` in `Map` and then multiply that price by quantity of each `Product`. I just don't know how to multiply these prices by quantities which are as values in the `Map`. Can anyone help me, please? I tried almost everything and nothing works.

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    //Attributes
    ...

    //Links

    Map<Product,Integer> products;

    //Constructor

    Transaction()
    {
        id = newTrId.incrementAndGet();
        date = new Date();
        products = new HashMap<>();
    }

    abstract void addProduct(Product aProduct, int aQuantity);


    BigDecimal calculateTotal()
    {
        BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);

        for(Product eachProduct : products.keySet())
        {
            total.add(eachProduct.getPrice());
        }
        for (Integer eachProduct : products.values())
        {

        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: `total.add(eachProduct.getPrice() * products.get(eachProduct));` This will grab the `Integer` in the `products` `Map` and multiply by the price of `eachProduct`. Add that in your `for-each` loop instead of doing another loop.

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal` is immutable and `add`does not change the object for which it is called. So you need to reassign the result of `add`:

```
BigDecimal calculateTotal() {
  BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
  for (Map.Entry<Product, Integer> entry : products.entrySet()) {
    total = total.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(entry.getKey().getPrice() * entry.getValue()));
  }
  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't know how to multiply these prices by quantities which are
>   as values in the `Map`. Can anyone help me, please?

It could be done by iterating over the **entries** of your `Map` in order to multiply the quantity (value of the `Map`) by its price like this:

```
BigDecimal calculateTotal() {
    BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
    for (Map.Entry<Product, Integer> entry : products.entrySet()) {
        total = total.add(
            BigDecimal.valueOf(entry.getKey().getPrice()).multiply(
                BigDecimal.valueOf(entry.getValue())
            )
        );
    }
    return total;
}
```

**NB:** I assume that `Product#getPrice()` returns a `double`.

**NB 2** As `BigDecimal` is **immutable**, you need re-assign your variable `total` at each iteration.

**NB 3** To avoid loosing any precision in your computation, you need to convert everything into `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Here take a look:

```
BigDecimal calculateTotal()
{
    BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);

    for(Product eachProduct : products.keySet())
    {
        total.add(eachProduct.getPrice() * products.get(eachProduct));
    }

    return total;
}
```

The only difference is this line: `total.add(eachProduct.getPrice() * products.get(eachProduct));`

I added this to grab the `Integer` from the map associated with the `Product`.

If using Java 8, you could do a stream as well.

```
total = new BigDecimal(map.keySet()
     .stream().mapToDouble( product -> product.getPrice() * products.get(product) )
     .sum());
```

Comment: Thank you, but NetBeans says that double cannot be converted to BigDecimal when I do this.

Comment: Hmmm, it worked when I tested it. Are you using Java 8?